# Runtime error when copying bytes from array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a copy of an array. I know this is "bad code" but I'm getting it from a tutorial that makes heavy use of this and other low-level things. For some reason I'm getting a runtime error and I can't tell where it's coming from or why. Can anyone help? Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>

void copy_array(void *a, void const *b, std::size_t size, int amount)
{
    std::size_t bytes = size * amount;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; ++i)
        reinterpret_cast<char *>(a)[i] = static_cast<char const *>(b)[i];
}

int main()
{
    int a[10], b[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    copy_array(a, b, sizeof(b), 10);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
}
```

Comment: Try printing `sizeof(b)`. Compare that to `sizeof(int)` and to `sizeof(int*)`. Now you've learned something. Namely that **arrays are *not* pointers!** No matter *who* told you that.

Comment: `sizeof(b)` returns the size in bytes already... you don't need to multiply it by 10.  And reinterpret cast?!?  Find a new tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `sizeof(b)` returns the size of the array in bytes not the number of elements in the array. This causes the copy function to overwrite the stack frame resulting in a runtime error. Use `sizeof(b[0])` instead to get the size of an individual element. If you want to retrieve the number of elements in an array you can use a combination of the two like so.

```
copy_array(a, b, sizeof(b[0]), sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]));
```

Comment: Pet peeve - `sizeof` doesn't need parentheses unless the argument is a type.  (My comment on the question was quoting the existing code, but you're creating new code! ;-P)

Comment: I understand...it's like restless leg syndrome ;)

Comment: I keep telling my sister that's so men can regulate temperature of sensitive equipment, but she keeps kicking my shins under the table....